# Proving f is discontinuous at every odd integer

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued function defined as

$$f(x)=x,\ \ \text{if}\ -1 \leq x \leq 1 $$

$$f(x+2)=f(x),\ \  \text{if}\ x\in\mathbb{R} \setminus [-1, 1] $$

Show that $f$ is discontinuous at every odd integer

**My Work**

Let $n=2m+1$ be an odd integer

**LHL**

$$
\lim_{{h \to 0}} f(n-h) \\
= \lim_{{h \to 0}} f(2m+1-h) \\
= \lim_{{h \to 0}} f(1-h+2m) \\  
= \lim_{{h \to 0}} 1-h \ \ (\text{using} \ f(x+2) = f(x))  \\ 
= 1 
$$

**RHL**

$$
\lim_{{h \to 0}} f(n-h) \\
= \lim_{{h \to 0}} f(2m+1+h) \\
= \lim_{{h \to 0}} f(1+h+2m) \\  
= \lim_{{h \to 0}} 1+h \ \ (\text{using} \ f(x+2) = f(x))  \\ 
= 1 
$$

I am getting both the limits as 1 however the RHL should be -1 as evident if we draw the graphical figure.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=\{x\}:=x-[x]$ where $[x]$ is the biggest integer which is no bigger than $x$, or "$\{$" is just the case symbol?

Comment: @Asigan it is just the case symbol, read as f(x) = x and f(x+2)=x

Comment: For the RH limit I think in your first line you mean $f(n+h)$ with $h>0$.  But then $f(1+h)$ is not $1+h$ since $1+h>1$.  You need $f(1+h)=f(1+h-2)=f(-1+h)=-1+h$.

Comment: I think there may be a typo in your question "$f(x+2)=x\ \ \text{if}\ \mathbb{R} \setminus [-1, 1]$". This would yield $f(x)=x-2$ for $x\notin [1,3]$. I think you mean $f(x+2)=f(x)$ (? )

Comment: I think David's answer is quite true. There are some advice in your writing: (1) In the post the case command is not needed. You can simply say "$f(x)=x$, $x\in [-1, 1]$, $f(x+2)=f(x)$, $x\notin [-1, 1]$" (2) In the one-side limit, you should write "$h\to 0+$, $h\to 0-$" instead of $h\to 0$.

Comment: Please fix the question. The statement $\text{if}\ \mathbb{R} \setminus [-1, 1]$ makes no sense.

Comment: @copper.hat It means for all R except the set [-1,1]

Comment: Please edit & repair the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I believe you are trying to define a period function whose values are given on the interval $[-1, 1]$, i.e. $f(x)= x$ on $[-1, 1]$ and for all other values of $x$, one "translates" $x$ left/right by steps of two until one obtains a value in $[-1,1]$ and then take that value as your input. So you should say something like $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x)= x$ and extend this to $\mathbb{R}$ via $f(x+2)= f(x)$ for all $x$.

Now as for your limit, you are somewhat on the correct path but you have forgotten what the limit means. Yes, we have $\lim_{h \to 0} (h + 2)= 2$ because as $h$ gets "close" to $0$, $h+ 2$ gets "close" to $2$ and you can "obtain" this by "plugging in" $h= 0$---that happens to be the answer. But the limit is about the journey, not the destination, i.e. what actually happens when $h= 0$, see the image below which I have always loved emphasizing while teaching.

Take your left hand limit at an odd integer. So say $n$ is odd. Because we are looking at the left hand limit, we need $\lim_{h \to 0^-} f(n+ h)$. You are fine using the fact that $n= 2m + 1$ for some integer $m$. But then we have....
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^-} f(n+ h)= \lim_{h \to 0^-} f(2m + 1 + h)= \lim_{h \to 0^-} f(1+h)
$$
You would want to explain how you know the $2m$ piece does not matter. Trying writing $2m$ as an $m$-fold sum of $2$'s and use an inductive argument.

Now $h$ is small but always less than 0 because we are taking the left-hand limit. But then $1+h \in [-1,1]$ so that $f(1+h)= 1+h$ and then the limit follows.

But for your right hand limit, think more carefully. You would have $\lim_{h \to 0^+} f(1+h)$. Then $h$ is "small" but always *greater* than 0. So then $1 +h \notin [-1,1]$. So you have to "translate" the value $1+h$ so that it is in the interval $[-1,1]$ so you can evaluate $f(1+h)$. This will then give you the negative value that you seek.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @mathematics2x2life